# Is it safe to call setImmediate recursively?

Tags: node.js

Is it safe to call `setImmediate()` recursively in (a reasonably up-to-date version of) NodeJS?

I have experimented with the following code and I haven't seen a stack overflow, or constant memory growth, but I can't find any documentation anywhere explicitly stating that this is safe to do:

```js
let i = 0;
(function runTest() {
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    setImmediate(runTest);
}());
```